# Display data from mongo after data is saved in state - React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks

I am creating an app with a search box, that when submitted will get data from mongo and display the data. The problem is I am unsure of how to ensure the data is fully saved in state before I display it. This leads to issues where it says "property x is undefined". I can't seen to find a definitive way of doing it and I am a beginner to React also.

 My current thinking is to use useEffect with a dependency array of *loading* to check when data is fully loaded before displaying data. But I am not sure where to set the state that the data has loaded and change *loading* to true 
 I have 3 parts currently **getData** (gets data from Mongo), **displayData** (attemping to display one field at the moment) and **render** 
 **getData**

```js
const getData = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // setLoading(true);
        fetch(API_URL + id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            setContact(data);
            setLoading(true);
        });
        console.log("DATA SAVED");
    };
```

**displayData**

```js
const displayExperience = (contact) => {
            return contact.experience.map((exp, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    <h3>{exp.company}</h3>
                </div>
            ));
        
    };
```

*NOTE:* experience is an array of objects, containing info on a contacts work experience. THis array of objects I beleive is causing the issue as I can display a single field of contact but cannot display anything within experience object due to undefined error

**render**

```html
return (
        <div className="App">
                <Form onSubmit={getData}>
                    <div className="App">
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label>ID</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Add ID" onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button className="mt-2" variant='dark' type="submit" >Submit</Button>
                    </div>
                </Form>
            <div>
                {displayExperience(contact)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

**States**

```js
const [contact, setContact] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [id, setId] = useState('');
```

Any suggestions for how best to save state fully so I can display without undefined errors. Again the issue seems to be as one of the fields returned is an array of objects. I beleive I should add a useEffect function and can be seen in *getData* where I attempted to set loading state.

Comment: The useEffect hook is used to perform side effects in the function components - and fetching data is a common example. When the submit happens, the handler can set the loading state (and the ui), which in turn can start the useEffect to populate (set the state of) the contact data. The dependency of the useEffect would be the loading state (which in turn depends upon the submit).

Comment: Note the useEffect will run on initial render and again on submit. You can also include a condition within the useEffect so that the fetch happens only once - the condition fields can any of the state (this in addition to the dependency).